# Make a responsive circle with content inside

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, responsive

I'm designing a website for my photography services and I would like to have the prices display in circles that are responsive on mobile.

This is how it looks on desktop:

[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLvBq.jpg)

Unfortunately it looks like this on mobile:

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZlPK.jpg)

This is the code I'm using for each circle:

```css
.pricessquarered {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 16px #d17461;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  color: #d17461;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricessquarered">
  <div>
    <h3><span style="color:#d17461">1 image</span></h3>
  <p>
    45€  
  </p>
    <hr>
  <p><span style="font-size:14px; color:black">
   USD $50
  </span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about having the circle countain the text as nicely as it does on dekstop?

Comment: You can use media queries to adjust the size of circles and font sizes of content to look nice in mobile resolution.

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7d5epxfu/ ? Let the content define the width/height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one way is to set a fixed width and height when screen size is less.

Second option is that you decrease the font size when the screen size is less.I have set 991px as breakpoint.You can take your own breakpoints.

```css
@media all and (max-width:991px){
.pricessquarered {
width:120px!important;
height:120px!important;
margin-bottom:10px!important;
}

.container{
flex-direction:column;
}

}

.container{
display:flex;
}

.pricessquarered {
  transition:all 0.3s;
  display:flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 16px #d17461;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  color: #d17461;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="pricessquarered">
  <div>
    <h3><span style="color:#d17461">1 image</span></h3>
  <p>
    45€  
  </p>
    <hr>
  <p><span style="font-size:14px; color:black">
   USD $50
  </span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pricessquarered" style="transition-delay:100ms;">
  <div>
    <h3><span style="color:#d17461">2 image</span></h3>
  <p>
    45€  
  </p>
    <hr>
  <p><span style="font-size:14px; color:black">
   USD $50
  </span></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pricessquarered" style="transition-delay:200ms;">
  <div>
    <h3><span style="color:#d17461">3 image</span></h3>
  <p>
    45€  
  </p>
    <hr>
  <p><span style="font-size:14px; color:black">
   USD $50
  </span></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be fixing my issue thank you! The only thing is that for some reasons the blocks aren't placing themselves on top of each other on tablet they just get smashed all together. I tried using min-max width specially for a tablet view with no luck.

Comment: For that, use flex-direction:column; when screen size is less.I have updated my answer.Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can appply `flex` to the `div` which is *inside*  `.pricessquarered`, with `flex-direction: column` and some additional settings (see below). You'll also need to remove the top and bottom margins of all its child elements to fit them into the container:

```css
.pricessquarered {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 16px #d17461;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  color: #d17461;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.pricessquarered>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.pricessquarered>div * {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricessquarered">
  <div>
    <h3><span style="color:#d17461">1 image</span></h3>
    <p>
      45€
    </p>
    <hr>
    <p><span style="font-size:14px; color:black">
   USD $50
  </span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

An additional note: The `flex` setting of your `.pricessquarered` only affects the `div` which is a direct child of `.pricessquarered`, not all the other elements inside it. It basically only centers that element inside its parent (which could be the `body`, but I can't see that from your code). The placement of all the other elements (with the exception of the text-centering) needs the additional settings I posted above.

Comment: I tried this one but on mobile the circles aren't nicely going around the content.

Comment: Then you need to change the sizes of either the circle divs or the font-sizes in a media query. That's a typical situation of what media queries are for.

Comment: Okay I think this works well enough. I couldn't get it to look good on tablet so I just removed the circles. It looks how I wanted on mobile. Thank you!